# Automatically Build Database Table based on a Class with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, class, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm really new to SQLAlchemy, and I love it. Right now I'm doing a lot of things manually and I want to do things more 'pythonically' and dynamic.

So as an example, I have this short script that manually creates/defines a table and then a function that inserts data into that table.

**database connection**

```
import os
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy import schema, types
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base  

db_url = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')
engine = create_engine(db_url)
Base = declarative_base(engine)
meta = Base.metadata
```

**table definition**

```
file_paths = Table('file_paths', meta,
    Column('table_id', Integer, primary_key = True),
    Column('fullpath', String(255)),
    Column('filename', String(255)),
    Column('extension', String(255)),
    Column('created', String(255)),
    Column('modified', String(255)),
    Column('size', Integer),
    Column('owner', String(255)),
    Column('permissions', Integer),
    mysql_engine='InnoDB',
)
file_paths.drop(engine, checkfirst = False)
file_paths.create(engine, checkfirst = True)
```

**insert function** takes a string and a list as arguments

```
def push_to_db(fullpath, fileInfo):
    i = file_paths.insert()
    i.execute(  fullpath    = str(fullpath), 
            filename    = str(fileInfo[0]),
            extension   = str(fileInfo[1]),
            created     = str(fileInfo[2]),
            modified    = str(fileInfo[3]),
            size        = str(fileInfo[4]),
            owner       = str(fileInfo[5]),
            permissions = str(fileInfo[6]),
         )
```

This works but it's ugly and taken right out of a tutorial I found somewhere online. My goal is to make these operations dynamic.

**example class**

```
class FileMeta(object):
    def __init__(self, fullPathFileName, filename):
        self.fullPathFileName = fullPathFileName
        self.filename = filename
        self.extension = os.path.splitext(self.filename)[1].lower()
        ...

    def fileMetaList(self):
        return [self.filename, self.extension, self.created, self.modified,\
                self.size, self.owner, self.permissions]
```

So here's the scenario: given a class object

1. define the table dynamically according to the class member variables

   - column numbers and names should correspond to variable names
   - or correspond to the index of that variable in a list of class variables
2. write a function that can insert data from the class into the corresponding dynamically created table

My intuition tells me this is what SQLAlchemy would be good for. Can someone tell me a good tutorial or reference that can outline this process?

Comment: You mean [declarative object-relational configuration](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/declarative.html)?

Comment: I'm not sure what I mean. I'm a total noob to SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You want to use the [declarative extension](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/index.html) instead:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class FilePaths(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'file_paths'
    __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine':'InnoDB'}

    table_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    fullpath = Column(String(255))
    filename = Column(String(255))
    extension = Column(String(255))
    created = Column(String(255))
    modified = Column(String(255))
    size = Column(Integer)
    owner = Column(String(255))
    permissions = Column(Integer)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

You can define your own `__init__()` as needed, as well other methods, then create instances of these to insert new rows.

See the [SQLAlchemy's own ORM tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html).

Comment: @laycat: this is *what the OP asked for*: a class definition that reflects the table row as an object. You can now use `FilePath` instances and they reflect database row contents transparently.

Comment: Would Base's AutoMap() also work for the dynamic creation of the tables? http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/extensions/automap.html

Comment: @DustyBoshoff looks like it is designed for that purpose, yes. Note that that extension was added in 0.9.1; this answer was written in the 0.8 days.

Comment: @DustyBoshoff: actually, `automapper` creates the declarative classes from an existing schema (albeit rudimentary ones); the OP was trying to create the classes manually (which gives you much more flexibility and control), but was using the wrong tools to do so.

Comment: is there a way to do that with classes from other files eg file_paths.py has class FilePaths and just to import it

Comment: @alkanschtein: that's... very broad and unclear. Check out the current [SQLAlchemy 2.0 ORM class mapping options](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/mapping_styles.html#orm-mapping-styles). You should be able to subclass existing classes to inherit their functionality, at the very least.

Answer (score 3):

Add Automap extension :

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base

# SQLAlchemy
engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)
metadata = MetaData()

Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
```